# Searching using Stream Builder

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
StreamBuilder (
    stream:FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(currUID).collection('Pinned').snapshots(),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> streamSnapshot) {
      if(streamSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      }
      // countPinned();
      if(streamSnapshot.data!.docs.length == 0  ){
        return Center(
          child: Text("No Pinned Notes yet.",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20 , fontFamily: "SpaceGrotesk",fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        );
      }else{
      return Expanded(
          child : 
            GridView.builder(
            
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
            itemCount: streamSnapshot.data!.docs.length,

            itemBuilder: (context , index){
                    if(streamSnapshot.data!.docs[index]['title'].toString().contains(searchText) || streamSnapshot.data!.docs[index]['body'].toString().contains(searchText)){
                return GestureDetector(
              onTap: (){
                Navigator.of(context).push(CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context){
                      return EditNotesScreen(title: streamSnapshot.data!.docs[index]['title'], body: streamSnapshot.data!.docs[index]['body'],date:streamSnapshot.data!.docs[index]['date'] , editedDate: streamSnapshot.data!.docs[index]['editedDate'] ,isPinned: true,);
                }));
                
              },
              
              child: NotesBox(title: streamSnapshot.data!.docs[index]['title'], body: streamSnapshot.data!.docs[index]['body'],));
            }else{
              return Center(
          child: Text("No Such Pinned Notes.",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20 , fontFamily: "SpaceGrotesk",fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        );
            }
            }

         , gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
          
            ));
      }
})
```

I am using a stream builder to search through a firestore DB. The searching works but if i have two notes in the database the searching stops after the second iteration. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

try this : i think it's because Center widget inside your itemBuilder

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(currUID).collection('Pinned').snapshots(),
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> streamSnapshot) {
    if (streamSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
    if (streamSnapshot.data!.docs.length == 0) {
      return Center(
        child: Text("No Pinned Notes yet.", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontFamily: "SpaceGrotesk", fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
      );
    } else {
      var matchingNotes = streamSnapshot.data!.docs.where((doc) => doc['title'].toString().contains(searchText) || doc['body'].toString().contains(searchText)).toList();

      if (matchingNotes.isEmpty) {
        return Center(
          child: Text("No Such Pinned Notes.", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontFamily: "SpaceGrotesk", fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        );
      } else {
        return Expanded(
          child: GridView.builder(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
            itemCount: matchingNotes.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              var note = matchingNotes[index];
              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                    return EditNotesScreen(
                      title: note['title'],
                      body: note['body'],
                      date: note['date'],
                      editedDate: note['editedDate'],
                      isPinned: true,
                    );
                  }));
                },
                child: NotesBox(title: note['title'], body: note['body']),
              );
            },
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: It did not work . Can you try and find another way through this problem ?